# WebFlux: proper way to multiple concatWith

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to concatinate multiple flux.

Is `flux1.concatWith(flux2).concatWith(flux3)` equal to `flux1.concatWith(flux2.concatWith(flux3))` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There operations is no difference, But the second one has extra memory copy.